# AspxTreeList Node Selection Problem

Tags: c#, devexpress

I'm trying to get focused node value, but in c# "treeList.FocusedNode" always returns null. Then i tried "CustomCallBack" event of the treelist to get node by key value, using "treeList.FindNodeByKeyValue()". I pass the key value but it still returns null. How can i fix this problem?

Here is the aspx codes of the TreeList:

```
<dxwtl:ASPxTreeList ID="trlGroup" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CssFilePath="~/App_Themes/Aqua/{0}/styles.css"
                                    CssPostfix="Aqua" ParentFieldName="TreeParentId" KeyFieldName="Id" ClientInstanceName="treeListItems"
                                    OnCustomCallback="trlGroup_CustomCallback" Visible="False" 
                                    >
                                    <ClientSideEvents FocusedNodeChanged="function(s,e) {
                                        var key = treeListItems.GetFocusedNodeKey();
                                        var isChild = treeListItems.GetNodeState(key);
                                        if(isChild == 'Child')
                                        {
                                            treeListItems.PerformCallback(key);
                                            gridItems.PerformCallback(key);
                                        }
                                        else
                                        {
                                            alert('Sadece en alt seviyeden seçim yapabilirsiniz.!');
                                        }
                    }" EndCallback="function(s,e){
                        if(s.cp_ShowPopup)
                        {
                            pcc_Question.Show();
                        }
                    }" />
                                    <Columns>
                                        <dxwtl:TreeListDataColumn FieldName="TreeParentId" Visible="false" VisibleIndex="0">
                                        </dxwtl:TreeListDataColumn>
                                        <dxwtl:TreeListDataColumn FieldName="ItemGroupCode" Caption="Master Code" VisibleIndex="1">
                                        </dxwtl:TreeListDataColumn>
                                        <dxwtl:TreeListDataColumn FieldName="ItemGroupDesc" Caption="Page Title" VisibleIndex="2" />
                                    </Columns>
```

and the C# code is like this :

```
protected void trlGroup_CustomCallback(object sender, DevExpress.Web.ASPxTreeList.TreeListCustomCallbackEventArgs e)
        {
            string key = e.Argument.ToString();
            TreeListNode treeNode = trlGroup.FindNodeByKeyValue(key);
            Session["ItemGroupDesc"] = treeNode["ItemGroupDesc"].ToString();
            Session["ItemGroupId"] = key;
        }
```

at "treeNode["ItemGroupDesc"].ToString()" .Net throws NullReferenceException. I looked at the trlGroup.Nodes and it's null.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please make certain that the ASPxTreeList is bound to its DataSource at every request to the server.  This should allow you to resolve the problem.  For more details, please refer to:

[Why might paging (sorting, grouping, filtering) not work in the ASPxGridView?](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/ViewKBIssue.aspx?kbid=K18183)